# Method not found error in Castor-XML jar file

Tags: java, maven

I have a simple maven project to do some SIF calls with MDM hub, and adding castor dependencies for this.

- Maven dependency added:

  org.codehaus.castor
        castor-xml
        1.4.1
- This downloaded the castor-xml-1.4.1.jar file.
- Right at the line calling sipClient.process(req) below exception is thrown

  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.exolab.castor.xml.Marshaller.getResolver()Lorg/exolab/castor/xml/ClassDescriptorResolver;
  at com.siperian.sif.message.CastorUtil.setMappingLoader(CastorUtil.java:470)
  at com.siperian.sif.message.CastorUtil.beanToXmlString(CastorUtil.java:358)
  at com.siperian.sif.message.CastorUtil.beanToXmlString(CastorUtil.java:323)
  at com.siperian.sif.message.CastorUtil.beanToXmlString(CastorUtil.java:309)
  at com.siperian.sif.message.CastorUtil.beanToXmlString(CastorUtil.java:295)
  at com.siperian.sif.client.HttpSiperianClient._process(HttpSiperianClient.java:117)
  at com.siperian.sif.client.SiperianClient.process(SiperianClient.java:179)

I can see the getResolver method and classDescriptorResolver in the jar file in Java Decompiler, Images

[classResolverDescriptor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfK3N.png)

[getResolver method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dciI.png)

Same exception even for 1.3.2 dependency.
Should I download any extra dependencies.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This specific error for 2 reasons:

1- You are missing the jar file that has this method (This might not be the issue you have, as you stated you can see it when looking at the decompiled jar)

2- You have 2 or more jars in your dependencies, and it is actually looking at the jar which does not have the method you need.

How you should approach this is as follows:

- Go to your ide, and open your pom.xml file
- Open the Dependency Heirarchy view and search for org.codehaus.castor or castor-xml and see how many different versions you have.

If you have more than 1, and some are included as part of another jar, you can use  in your pom.xml to remove the versions which you dont want.

If you like command line you can probably do the above, using mvn dependency:tree

Hope this helps you in some way.

-- Edited --

Your code is using 1.3.2 dependency.  How? You can download the castor-xml.1.3.2.jar and extract it and look into the Marshaller.  You will see the method getResolver() does not take any parameters, and therefore you get NoMethodFound.

´´´

```
/**
 * Returns the ClassDescriptorResolver for use during marshalling
 *
 * @return the ClassDescriptorResolver
 * @see #setResolver
 */
public XMLClassDescriptorResolver getResolver() {


}
```

´´´

Therefore you need to find out in your dependency hierarchy, will one includes this 1.3.2 jar and exclude this jar from it.

An example of how to do exclude is in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>sample.group.which.has.castor.in.it</groupId>
  <artifactId>artifactor.which.has.castor.in.it</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
      <groupId>org.codehaus.castor</groupId>
      <artifactId>castor-xml</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.2</version>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions> 
</dependency>
<dependency> <!-- add proper dependency also, as it is needed -->
    <groupId>org.codehaus.castor</groupId>
    <artifactId>castor-xml</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I deleted all contents of .m2 folder and did maven update as repository folder had some old castor version folders. 
but even with just the latest versions - I still have the same exception of method not found. 
I have checked the line where exception started at com.siperian.sif.message.CastorUtil.setMappingLoader(CastorUtil.java:470)
at line 470 it is calling Marshaller  which points to org.exolab.castor.xml.Marshaller
not sure why it is not able to detect the method - cleaned and Maven updated the project several times.

Comment: @ApuroopaKatralapalli It is not your .m2 repo that you should be looking at.  It is your project pom.xml file.  Open it in your IDE and look at your heirarchy of that pom.xml there.  Search for the jar name there.

Comment: yes I can see castor-xml : 1.3.2 underresolved dependencies in Dependency Hierarchy

Comment: @ApuroopaKatralapalli I modified my answer to show you how to use exclusion.  You need to see which artifactor includes this 1.3.2 by default, and exclude it in your pom.xml file and hopefully that should resolve your issue